# how to cast view to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello every one i trying to cast view to fragment but it is showing the errror cant cast view to fragment please give me solution how i can do this. I am using this in baseadapter of a listview

**thanks and my code is here**

**It is shwoing error in pages.add();**

```
package okay.adapters;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.Okay.Webservices.Service_LikeImage;
import com.okay.R;
import com.okay.comments.OkayComments;
import com.okay.fonts.fontsFamily;
import com.okay.lazyloading.ImageLoaderRelativeLayout;
import com.okay.lazyloading.mageLoaderWallUserImage;
import com.okay.properties.okayWallProps;

public class wallAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    wallAdapterProps objProp = new wallAdapterProps();

    ImageLoaderRelativeLayout imageLoader_RelativeLayout;
    mageLoaderWallUserImage imageLoader;
    int imagePsotioninPager;
    public wallAdapter(Fragment act, List<okayWallProps> wallData) {
        objProp.wallDataList = wallData; 
        objProp.activity = act.getActivity();
        objProp.context = objProp.activity.getApplicationContext();
        imageLoader_RelativeLayout = new ImageLoaderRelativeLayout(
                objProp.context);
        imageLoader = new mageLoaderWallUserImage(objProp.context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objProp.wallDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) objProp.activity
                    .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_walllayout, null);
        }

        // Get Controls

        final viewHolder vh = new viewHolder();
        vh.txtview_Question = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        vh.textview_CommentCount = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textVew_WallTotalComments);
        vh.textview_LikeCount = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textVew_WallTotalokay);
        vh.ViewPager_Images = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vh.imageview_Profile = (ImageView) v 
                .findViewById(R.id.imageview_userImage);
        vh.textview_PostDate=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_PostDate);

        vh.textview_UserName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textVew_WallUserName);



        // SetDatato controls




        //Set Data
        vh.txtview_Question
                .setText(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Name);
        vh.txtview_Question.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));



        vh.textview_UserName.setText(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_User_Name);
        vh.textview_UserName.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));


        vh.textview_PostDate.setText(convertDate(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Date));
        vh.textview_PostDate.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),false));






        // Set pager

        Vector<Fragment> pages = new Vector<Fragment>();

        for (int i = 0; i < objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data
                .size(); i++) {

            final int imagePosion=i;
            LayoutInflater mInflaterImage = (LayoutInflater) objProp.activity
                    .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View vImage = mInflaterImage.inflate(R.layout.wallimagepageradaper, null);

            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)vImage.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)vImage.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            imageLoader_RelativeLayout.DisplayImage(objProp.wallDataList
                    .get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(i).qst_Wall_Image,
                    imageView);


            //Get Controls
        /*  vh.textView_Percentage=(TextView)vImage.findViewById(R.id.textView_PercentCount);
            vh.textView_percentVoteCount=(TextView)vImage.findViewById(R.id.textView1_PercentVoteCount);

            //Set Data
            vh.textView_Percentage.setText(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(i).qst_Wall_Image_Percentage+"%");
            vh.textView_Percentage.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));



            vh.textView_percentVoteCount.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));
            vh.textView_percentVoteCount.setText(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(i).qst_Wall_Image_LikeCount+" Votes");

            */




            chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    new Service_LikeImage(objProp.activity).execute(objProp.wallDataList
                    .get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(imagePosion).qst_Wall_ImageID+""); 

                }
            });




            /*//RelativeLayout layoutImage=new RelativeLayout(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext());



            vh.imageView_PostImage = new ImageView(objProp.context);
            vh.imageView_PostImage.setId(getID());
            imageLoader_RelativeLayout.DisplayImage(objProp.wallDataList
                    .get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(i).qst_Wall_Image,
                    vh.imageView_PostImage);*/

            pages.add(object)
        }

        CustomPagerAdapter adap = new CustomPagerAdapter(objProp.activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),pages);
        vh.ViewPager_Images.setAdapter(adap);









        vh.ViewPager_Images.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                vh.textview_CommentCount.setText(objProp.wallDataList
                        .get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(arg0).qst_Wall_Image_CommentCount
                        + " Comments");

                vh.textview_CommentCount.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));


                vh.textview_LikeCount.setText(objProp.wallDataList
                        .get(position).wallPost_Images_Data.get(arg0).qst_Wall_Image_LikeCount
                        + " Okay");
                vh.textview_LikeCount.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));

                imagePsotioninPager=arg0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });

        vh.textview_CommentCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(objProp.activity, OkayComments.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("wallPostPosition", position);
                intent.putExtra("imageNumber",imagePsotioninPager );
                objProp.activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

         imageLoader.DisplayImage(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_User_Image,
         vh.imageview_Profile);

        String totComments = objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data
                .get(0).qst_Wall_Image_CommentCount + "";

        vh.textview_CommentCount
                .setText(totComments+" Comments");
        vh.textview_CommentCount.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));

        vh.textview_LikeCount
                .setText(objProp.wallDataList.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data
                        .get(0).qst_Wall_Image_LikeCount + " Okay");

        vh.textview_LikeCount.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(objProp.activity.getApplicationContext(),true));


        return v;

    }

    public class viewHolder {
        TextView txtview_Question;
        TextView textview_CommentCount;
        TextView textview_LikeCount;
        TextView textview_UserName;
        TextView textview_PostDate;
        ViewPager ViewPager_Images;
        ImageView imageview_Profile;


        /*TextView textView_Percentage;
        TextView textView_percentVoteCount;
        */

        // Image in ViewPager
        ImageView imageView_PostImage;

    }

    public int getID() {

        int max = 1000000;
        int min = 0;
        // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }


    private String  convertDate(String strngdate) {



            SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            java.util.Date date = null;
            try 
            {

                date = form.parse(strngdate);
            } 

            catch (ParseException e) 
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
            String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
            return newDateStr;
    }


    public String getFormattedDate( long smsTimeInMilis) {
        Calendar smsTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        smsTime.setTimeInMillis(smsTimeInMilis);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        final String timeFormatString = "h:mm aa"; 
        final String dateTimeFormatString = "EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm aa";
        final long HOURS = 60 * 60 * 60;
        if(now.get(Calendar.DATE) == smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) ){
            return "Today " + DateFormat.format(timeFormatString, smsTime);
        }else if(now.get(Calendar.DATE) - smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1 ){
            return "Yesterday " + DateFormat.format(timeFormatString, smsTime);
        }else if(now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == smsTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
            return DateFormat.format(dateTimeFormatString, smsTime).toString();
        }else 
            return DateFormat.format("MMMM dd yyyy, h:mm aa", smsTime).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You just cannot do that. Those are Classes with different purposes.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: so how can i do this . because i have a layout in vImage varibale and i want to add that is fragment .

Comment: it is my project requirment.

Comment: do you have solution how i can do this

Comment: First, show your whole Adapter code, so I can help you.

Comment: ok i i am going to update the code

Comment: it is containg so many comments

Comment: If you want vImage to be your list Item resource, you have to do that in getView() method. Your ViewHolder has to hold only Views belonging to R.layout.wallimagepageradaper. If that is not what you want, pay attention to Dan S answer.

Answer (score 0):

`View` and `Fragment` objects cannot be casted to another as they have very different super classes and neither is an Interface. If you don't understand why I suggest continuing to read at http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment layou, add `class ="...."`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this (casting the View to Fragment) , but if you need to get your added fragment, say you add a fragment using the support fragment manager then you can get the current fragment from UI by TAG

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
```